# Short story or novelette about a planet where sex is not taboo

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novella

I think I read this short Sci-Fi story (or maybe a novelette) about 20-25 years ago. Can't remember where, and I'm sorry but I can't remember more details. It was probably published earlier, but I didn't get the chance to read it upon publishing as I was only fourteen 25 years ago.

It's about a space traveler that finds an "unknown" planet where sex is not taboo among human(oid?) colonists. The planet is rich and he wants it incorporated into the Galactic Empire (or something like that) only to find out that other people already know about the planet and are disgusted by it, they don't want anything to do with them.

I've tried Googling, but it always brings up some other works. Maybe I misremembered something, it's been a long time since I read it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you have any idea _where_ you read it?  Was it online, in an anthology or in a magazine?

Comment: @DavidW Sorry, but as I mentioned - I can't remember. It was probably in some magazine, as I didn't have reliable internet access back then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

["If All Men Were Brothers, Would You Want One to Marry Your Sister"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_All_Men_Were_Brothers,_Would_You_Let_One_Marry_Your_Sister%3F) by Theodore Sturgeon

In the story a man is seeking the origin of some remarkable items and traces them to the planet Vexvelt - a planet where sex (including incest) is not taboo (and is in fact, encouraged), and which is shunned by nearby planets aware of their practices.

It was originally published in *Dangerous Visions* and has been reprinted [often](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41293).

Comment: For the love of....... How?? I have been trying to find this for a week, and you gave me the answer within few minutes? That's it, thank you! Ironically, Google has sent me to some other works by Theodore Sturgeon, but that wasn't it, didn't think about exploring it further.

Comment: It's a memorable story - and I happened to remember its unusual title